# How long does Legendary Resistance last?

Tags: dnd-5e, duration, resistance

I read recently—unfortunately I can't remember where, or I'd link it—that when a creature uses its Legendary Resistance, that resistance lasts a minute. According to this, for example, if I cast Bestow Curse on Strahd and he failed the saving throw and used his Legendary Resistance, I couldn't put him under the effects of Bestow Curse for 10 rounds. Looking through the books I have, however, I can't find any reference to this.

How long does Legendary Resistance last?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## It lasts for one roll

The ability says:

> ***Legendary Resistance (3/Day).*** If the (creature) fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

If the creature uses this ability and then needs to make another save, even in the same round, the previous use of the ability provides no protection.

Comment: "The previous use of the ability provides no protection" might not be worded wisely. It makes it sound like this sequence makes sense: Evil Wizard casts Sleep, roll to save, fail, Legendary Resistance, casts Fireball, You fall asleep because you need to save for half damage.

Comment: @candied_orange that's just not how saving throws work in 5e. Once you have succeeded it failed against the effect causing the saving throw that's it (unless the specific spell makes creatures make multiple saving throws, in which case each saving throw is its own thing).

Comment: @candied_orange That's a bad example since the sleep spell has no saving throw in 5E.

Answer (score 7):

### It affects a single failed saving throw but doesn't really have a duration

If you look at the *Legendary Resistance* ability, it says this:

> ***Legendary Resistance (3/Day).*** If [Strahd] fails a saving throw, he can choose to succeed instead.

It's not a continuous ability with a duration, it affects the single failed save and then it ends. Typically, the creature would have 3 uses per day of this, and if it needs to use it again, it has to burn another use. It's a discrete event, not a continuous thing that lets you benefit multiple times from the same instance of it.

There is nothing in official content that would make a *Legendary Resistance* last for a minute – so wherever you read this, it wasn't an official 5E sourcebook. It could have been some weird homebrew rule, or another system entirely.